# Group Records with less than one hour separation and count how many per group

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I'm new here, please HELP!...and since I'm new, I can't post any images to help explain.

I'm trying to group sets of data based on time separations between records and then count how many records are in each group.

In the example below, I want to return the count for each group of data, so Group 1=5, Group 2=5 and Group 3=5

```
SELECT AREA_ID AS "AREA ID",
LOC_ID         AS "LOCATION ID",
TEST_DATE      AS "DATE",
TEST_TIME      AS "TIME"
FROM MON_TEST_MASTER
WHERE AREA_ID   =89
AND LOC_ID      ='3015'
AND TEST_DATE   ='10/19/1994';


AREA ID LOCATION ID DATE        TIME
89      3015        10/19/1994  8:00:22
89      3015        10/19/1994  8:00:22
89      3015        10/19/1994  8:19:55
89      3015        10/19/1994  8:19:55
89      3015        10/19/1994  8:41:22
89      3015        10/19/1994  11:35:47
89      3015        10/19/1994  11:35:47
89      3015        10/19/1994  11:35:47
89      3015        10/19/1994  11:35:47
89      3015        10/19/1994  11:35:47
89      3015        10/19/1994  15:13:46
89      3015        10/19/1994  15:13:46
89      3015        10/19/1994  15:13:46
89      3015        10/19/1994  15:13:46
89      3015        10/19/1994  15:13:46
```

Group 1 = 8:00:22 to 8:41:22

Group 2 = 11:35:47 to 11:35:47

Group 3 = 15:13:46 to 15:13:46

Keep in mind the times will always change, and sometime go over the one hour mark, but no group will have more then a one hour separation between records.

I hope this makes sense...PLEASE HELP!

Comment: What happens if you have a row with 9:01:00? In which group does it go?

Comment: Group 2 = `11:35:47` to `11:35:47` and Group 3 = `15:13:46` to `15:13:46`? What is the group dividing logic?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If your records have 5 min difference between then, over 5 hours time, under the premise that the groups include records within one hour lapse, the same record should be included in more than one group. Or do you want to get the number of records for each hour?

Comment: It would go in Group 1 because the time is closer to the last record in Group 1 then the first record in Group 2. But I see your point, but it will likely never happen that a record is more then an hour apart from the set it belongs to. The Groups are dividing test intervals throughout the day. I hope this helps, if not let me know and I will further explain as best I can. THANK YOU!

Comment: I would've assumed 9:01 would be in its own group. To not do so would make this much more difficult to pin down as we're now making exceptions to the one hour separation rule for individual outliers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, 9:01 would be in it's own group